# Wrap and scale text in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, wrapfigure

I am trying to wrap my text around the following picture but it doesn't seem to be working.

This is my MWE. And I have been trying to use `wrapfigure` but its not working the way I want to do.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{stanli}
%HERE WE GO
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}

\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}
 
    \scaling{.25};
    \point{a}{0}{0};
    \point{b}{0}{5};
    \point{c}{10}{5};
    \point{d}{10}{0};
    \point{e}{15}{5};
    \point{f}{14.3}{5};
    \point{g}{10}{9};
    \point{x}{0}{7};
    \point{z}{12}{0};

    \beam{1}{a}{b}[0][0];
    \beam{1}{b}{c}[0][5];
    \beam{1}{c}{d}[10][5];
    \beam{1}{d}{a}[10][5];
    
    
    \support {1}{a}[-90];
    \support {1}{b}[-90];
    
    \dimensioning{1}{b}{c}{-1}[$10.0m$];
    \dimensioning{2}{c}{d}{-1.5}[$5.0m$];
    
    \load {1}{c}[90][1];
    \load {1}{e}[180][1];
    \load {1}{x}[270][1];
    \load {1}{z}[180][1];
    %\notation {1}{g}{5 kN}[ above left];
    \notation {5}{c}{f}[$2 kN$ ][.7];
    \notation {5}{c}{g}[$5 kN$ ][.7];
    \notation {1}{x}{y}[ below right];
    \notation {5}{d}{z}[$x$ ][.7];
    %\load {1}{c}

      
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{2D Model in question} \label{fig:2D Model in Question}
\end{figure}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris dignissim egestas ligula et egestas. Fusce volutpat odio et mollis lacinia. Suspendisse at euismod leo. Pellentesque interdum est sed tellus luctus, id congue mi dapibus. Duis molestie faucibus porta. Donec at turpis sed dui sollicitudin porta. Maecenas nec pharetra orci, ultrices malesuada nisi. Sed mollis et nibh ut sagittis. Quisque accumsan lacus et dui elementum luctus quis sed ex. Fusce sed massa iaculis, pellentesque urna in, pharetra velit. Integer lobortis eu ante ullamcorper blandit.

Nulla vestibulum ut nisi in dictum. Sed blandit eros dui, ut accumsan felis viverra a. Nunc quis ante non risus tincidunt ultricies. Quisque luctus consequat lacinia. Cras ullamcorper lectus dolor, nec auctor urna accumsan eu. Donec leo tortor, sollicitudin sed dui sed, interdum scelerisque lacus. Quisque sagittis varius metus, ut consectetur est. Vestibulum id fermentum ligula. Vestibulum eros mauris, fringilla sit amet quam id, tincidunt porttitor ligula. Quisque vitae varius quam.

Ut tristique semper est in sollicitudin. Phasellus ultricies elementum mauris eget ullamcorper. Proin sit amet lacus vel enim semper vestibulum vitae vitae purus. Duis imperdiet consequat libero, ac faucibus urna semper at. Suspendisse id tempor dui. In volutpat urna mauris, et tristique quam fermentum sed. Vestibulum suscipit interdum euismod. Aliquam scelerisque lobortis felis, quis lobortis massa malesuada id. Curabitur at blandit orci.

\end{document}
```

I actually want to achieve something like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please include the code of a small *complete* document starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, including your attempt with `wrapfigure`, otherwise we can hardly tell you what you are doing wrong. Did you try `wrapfigure` instead of `figure` (see [Wrapping text around figures](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Wrapping_text_around_figures))?

Comment: Hello thank you gernot! I have edited the coded. I have tried but the problem occours with scaling. I attachted my code without wrapfigure to not confuse the reader. I wish for it to remain around the same size as currently.

Comment: What exactly did you try with `wrapfigure`? If I remove the spurious `\scalebox` line (which just causes an error), replace `\begin{figure}[H]` with `\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.6\linewidth}`, and `\end{figure}` with `\end{wrapfigure}` it seems to work fine.

Comment: Sorry, meant `\resizebox`, not `\scalebox`, in my previous comment.

Comment: Please don't try not to confuse us. It is confusing if the given code does not demonstrate the problem. Often the problem is in some other place than the poster thinks (otherwise the poster might have found the problem themself), and if the real problematic part is left out, then there is nothing to debug.

Comment: Thank you for your help Torbjørn!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SX! I don’t see a problem in using the `wrapfig` package. Turning Torbjørn T.’s comment into an answer:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{supertabular, wrapfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{stanli}
%HERE WE GO

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.6\linewidth}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}

% \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}  

    \scaling{.25};
    \point{a}{0}{0};
    \point{b}{0}{5};
    \point{c}{10}{5};
    \point{d}{10}{0};
    \point{e}{15}{5};
    \point{f}{14.3}{5};
    \point{g}{10}{9};
    \point{x}{0}{7};
    \point{z}{12}{0};

    \beam{1}{a}{b}[0][0];
    \beam{1}{b}{c}[0][5];
    \beam{1}{c}{d}[10][5];
    \beam{1}{d}{a}[10][5];
    
    
    \support {1}{a}[-90];
    \support {1}{b}[-90];
    
    \dimensioning{1}{b}{c}{-1}[$10.0m$];
    \dimensioning{2}{c}{d}{-1.5}[$5.0m$];
    
    \load {1}{c}[90][1];
    \load {1}{e}[180][1];
    \load {1}{x}[270][1];
    \load {1}{z}[180][1];
    %\notation {1}{g}{5 kN}[ above left];
    \notation {5}{c}{f}[$2 kN$ ][.7];
    \notation {5}{c}{g}[$5 kN$ ][.7];
    \notation {1}{x}{y}[ below right];
    \notation {5}{d}{z}[$x$ ][.7];
    %\load {1}{c}

      
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{2D Model in question} \label{fig:2D Model in Question}
\end{wrapfigure}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris dignissim egestas ligula et egestas. Fusce volutpat odio et mollis lacinia. Suspendisse at euismod leo. Pellentesque interdum est sed tellus luctus, id congue mi dapibus. Duis molestie faucibus porta. Donec at turpis sed dui sollicitudin porta. Maecenas nec pharetra orci, ultrices malesuada nisi. Sed mollis et nibh ut sagittis. Quisque accumsan lacus et dui elementum luctus quis sed ex. Fusce sed massa iaculis, pellentesque urna in, pharetra velit. Integer lobortis eu ante ullamcorper blandit.

Nulla vestibulum ut nisi in dictum. Sed blandit eros dui, ut accumsan felis viverra a. Nunc quis ante non risus tincidunt ultricies. Quisque luctus consequat lacinia. Cras ullamcorper lectus dolor, nec auctor urna accumsan eu. Donec leo tortor, sollicitudin sed dui sed, interdum scelerisque lacus. Quisque sagittis varius metus, ut consectetur est. Vestibulum id fermentum ligula. Vestibulum eros mauris, fringilla sit amet quam id, tincidunt porttitor ligula. Quisque vitae varius quam.

Ut tristique semper est in sollicitudin. Phasellus ultricies elementum mauris eget ullamcorper. Proin sit amet lacus vel enim semper vestibulum vitae vitae purus. Duis imperdiet consequat libero, ac faucibus urna semper at. Suspendisse id tempor dui. In volutpat urna mauris, et tristique quam fermentum sed. Vestibulum suscipit interdum euismod. Aliquam scelerisque lobortis felis, quis lobortis massa malesuada id. Curabitur at blandit orci.

\end{document}
```

This should result in:

[image]

Im am not sure what the line `\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}` should do, so I commented it out.